# Записываю json в переменную получаю Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript

Записываю json в переменную:

```
    var json = "{
                  'positions': {
                    '0':{
                          'id':'1',
                          'name':'one'
                        },
                    '1':{
                          'id':'2',
                          'name':'two'
                        },
                    '2':{
                          'id':'3',
                          'name':'three'
                        }
                  }
                }";
```

Получаю ошибку (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL) на строку:   var json = "{

Я конечно переписал так и ошибок не возникает:

```
    var json = JSON.stringify({
                  'positions': {
                    '0':{
                          'id':'1',
                          'name':'one'
                        },
                    '1':{
                          'id':'2',
                          'name':'two'
                        },
                    '2':{
                          'id':'3',
                          'name':'three'
                        }
                  }
                });
```

В чем криминал то в первом куске кода?

Comment: кодировка utf8 без BOM в notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что строки в JavaScript переносятся не так. Либо так:

```
var json = "{\n"
   + "               'positions': {\n"
   + "                 '0':{\n"
   + "                       'id':'1',\n"
   + "                       'name':'one'\n"
   + "                     },\n"
   + "                 '1':{\n"
   + "                       'id':'2',\n"
   + "                       'name':'two'\n"
   + "                     },\n"
   + "                 '2':{\n"
   + "                       'id':'3',\n"
   + "                       'name':'three'\n"
   + "                     }\n"
   + "               }\n"
   + "             }";
```

Либо так (обратите внимание на кавычки):

```
var json = `{
                  'positions': {
                    '0':{
                          'id':'1',
                          'name':'one'
                        },
                    '1':{
                          'id':'2',
                          'name':'two'
                        },
                    '2':{
                          'id':'3',
                          'name':'three'
                        }
                  }
                }`;
```

Comment: буду знать.благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант - экранировать перенос строки:

```
var json = "{\
  'positions': {\
    '0':{\
          'id':'1',\
          'name':'one'\
        },\
    '1':{\
          'id':'2',\
          'name':'two'\
        },\
    '2':{\
          'id':'3',\
          'name':'three'\
        }\
  }\
}";
```